# UITableView Margined/In Header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

[image: Contact's TableView]

I'm looking to create the TableView section contained in the header of this tableview (the "margined" area with Eric Mulder typed in). Does anybody have any insight on this matter? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it easily with a delegate method of *UITableView*. I got it to work by creating an image which contains a the style of the default cells of a table view. Then I simply load it as an *UIImageView* in my header view of the table view.
For example, you can take a look at my app iCookit ([App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/icookit/id434101111?mt=8)). You can see the work on the 3rd picture. That's the result. It was very easy to do. Just a little bit with Photoshop or Gimp.

Comment: Right that's exatly what I'm looking for, but are those cells selectable? The ones in the header? Also, if you do load in the header with an image, how can dynamically modify the text within those cells? Thanks!

Comment: If there should be the possibility to dynamically modify the text, you can add a _UITextView_ within the _UIImageView_. Check that `userInteractionEnabled` is set to true. If they should be selectable, you can create a button and add the image as background image and add a new image as highlighted image. In this case, you have to create two images, one for normal and the other one for highlighted state.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a `UIView` that contains both the photo well and a `UITableView` for the name fields as the main `UITableView`'s `headerView`?

Comment: No have you made this work with this method? My concern with this method is that the TableView's header will be scrollable itself, and not move seamlessly with the whole TableView

Comment: I haven’t tried it, but I see no reason why it shouldn’t work. Make sure you disable scrolling (`-[UIScrollView setScrollEnabled:]`) and properly set the frame size (deriving it from `-[UITableView contentSize]` after the table view has loaded its data).

Comment: Yea that makes perfect sense to me, my only concern is that apple would have an issue with 2 tableViews in a single view, but your solution would definitely work. Thanks!

Comment: I see no reason why they would have a problem with that.